# Retaining SelectedItem when Bound ItemSource changes

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a list of Languages bound to a combobox ItemSource.  From time-to-time, the list of Languages can change.  When this happens, the SelectedItem is wiped out.  Because Binding is used, re-assigning the old value does not seem to work.  The combobox has

```
ItemSource = "{Binding Languages, IsAsync = true}"
SelectedItem = "{Binding SelectedLanguage}"
```

In code, I have (roughly)

```
var prevLanguage = this.SelectedLanguage;
this.Languages = newLanguages;

if (this.Languages.Keys.Contains(prevLanguage))
  this.SelectedLanguage = prevLanguage;
else
  this.SelectedLanguage = myDefaultLanguage;
```

This apparently happens too soon, because the combobox selected item still goes to blank.  It does not get set to either prevLanguage or myDefaultLanguage.  How can I make sure that the SelectedLanguage gets set after the binding is complete on the ItemSource?

Comment: In which event handler does this code run?

Comment: Ahh, that was a good comment, in the last versions of my program, I had Binding Languages IAsync = true.

Comment: Well, I don't usually go with writing NotifyPropertyChanged myself, but you may try SelectionChanged event to take a note on the selected item.

Comment: IsAsync was the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is IsAsync true in the Languages.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if you use Text, instead of selected item.

```
      <ComboBox ItemSource = "{Binding Languages, IsAsync = true}"
                      Text = "{Binding SelectedLanguage}"
```

By the way,  instead of using

```
         if (this.Languages.Keys.Contains(prevLanguage))
```

you could do

```
       if (this.Languages.ContainKey(prevLanguage))
```